# Blazor Webassembly Core Hosted Debugging not working

Tags: debugging, blazor, google-chrome-devtools, blazor-webassembly

I have built a WebApp based on Blazor in my company. However, I am not able to debug. The breakpoints are not bound. A call to chrome `--remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\marco.gall\AppData\Local\Temp\blazor-chrome-debug" https://localhost:44307/` loads a new Chrome instance, but the result is the same. I have googled a lot, but I can't find a solution to my problem.